# react-admin typescript: Cannot use namespace as a type

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I'm trying to add somes files from the react-admin example demo, and i have somes errors:

`Cannot use namespace 'FilterProps' as a type.`

Code example:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/orders/OrderList.tsx

```
const OrderFilter: FC<Omit<FilterProps, 'children'>> = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <SearchInput source='q' alwaysOn />
    <ReferenceInput source='user_id' reference='users'>
      <AutocompleteInput
        optionText={(choice: Customer) =>
          choice.first_name && choice.last_name
            ? `${choice.first_name} ${choice.last_name}`
            : ''
        }
      />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <DateInput source='date_gte' />
    <DateInput source='date_lte' />
    <TextInput source='total_gte' />
    <NullableBooleanInput source='returned' />
  </Filter>
);
```

Same error for Identifier and ListProps.

Also, in the import FilterProps, Identifier, ListProps have messages "is declared but its value is never read"

I already used .tsx for customize the layout AppBar, etc. without errors.
The code was copied from github without modification.

Where the errors came from?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors goes with this imports:

```
import { Identifier } from 'ra-core';
import { ListProps, DatagridProps, FilterProps } from 'ra-ui-materialui';
```